# How do I find out if my sql query is Null?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm querying my database for the user's youtube username.  If it is Null, I need a "Missing Username" to appear.  I can't figure out how to find out if the result is null or not.

```
$getyoutube = "SELECT cb_youtubeusername FROM #__comprofiler WHERE id=$userid";

$db->setQuery($getyoutube);

$youtubeusername=$db->loadresult() or die(mysql_error());

if ($youtubeusername== NULL){
echo "Missing Username";}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm do you use PDO? Or is it your own class?

Comment: `var_dump($youtubeusername)`

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!isset($youtubeusername['cb_youtubeusername'])){
  echo "Missing Username";
}
```

or

```
if(!isset($youtubeusername){
  echo "Missing Username";
}
```

I don't know how you displaying query results.

Comment: Still not working.  Basically, I'm querying for youtubeusername, and want to ignore it if it comes back empty or null.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `mysql_error` you should be able to use [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/mysql_num_rows) to find out how many records you are dealing with.

After that you will probably want to use [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array) or one of the `mysql_fetch_*` functions to get the values from the record(s).

Also, before asking questions you really should use `var_dump()` or `print_r()` to figure out what is in the variables you are using. If you had you would probably be able to help yourself.

Comment: I think that, this `$db->loadresult()` fetch results. But this is only divination ;)